# make sqlite user defined function not trigger on empty selects

Tags: javascript, sqlite, user-defined-functions, sql.js

I'm using sql.js (compiled via emscripten from sqlite to js) and when i run a UDF on a selection result that return empty rows, the system complains that the number of arguments doesn't match (0, versus the number I expect when there are results).

Is there a way to simply *not call the UDF when the results are empty* --- I could always get the query results in js, check the cardinality, and then trigger the UDF, but i want a solution that's contained in just SQL.

This is an example `SELECT drawRect(x, y, width, height, color) FROM rectTable`, where drawRect is registered as UDF that takes in 5 variables.

Thanks sos much!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not a problem. It already does the desired behavior. My bug was else where. Sorry.